# How to add a key event handler that listens for the Space key?

Tags: javascript, html

Button is open if user press enter (and button is in focus). But I want to open link button also when user press space button.

Buttons are expected to be triggered using the Space key, while links are expected to be triggered through the Enter key. In other words, when links are used to behave like buttons, adding role="button" alone is not sufficient. It will also be necessary to add a key event handler that listens for the Space key in order to be consistent with native buttons.
How to do that?

```
  <a tabindex="0" title="Show project filter" class="button button-image img-button-select" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="divFilterDetails" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Does the user can type space "everywhere" in the web page to trigger this link ? What is the behaviour of the link ? Redirecting ? Processing data ?

Comment: User can type space only when link button is in focus. Link for example open popup with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Add keypress event on every link where exist role="button"
        $(document).on('keypress', 'a[role="button"]', null, onKeypressButton, false);
    });


function onKeypressButton(e) {
    //Need both, 'keyCode' and 'which' to work in all browsers.
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which,
        spaceKey = 32;
    //If user press space key:
    if (code == spaceKey) {
        //Do same thing as onclick:
        $(e.currentTarget).click();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `keypress` event for this. Sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrgmxL1q/).